# EF6 Find function always go to the DB

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I was wondering why Entity Framework in my code was so "chatty" with the DB.
after searching in Microsoft documentation, I found that normally, when using "T DbSet.Find(params object keys)", it should first check in the ObjectStateManager to see if the entity hasn't been loaded yet into memory, if yes it should return this in-memory entity, if not then fetch it from the store. (ref to the article : [Caching in the Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#3-caching-in-the-entity-framework)

[image: screenshot of microsoft documentation]

however, after doing some really basic testing in a console app, I can't get to this behaviour.

In that console app (C#10, .NET Core 6, EF6), I already have the table with a primary key on SQL server 2022. So I just created a Class Inheriting from DbContext and added a DbSet of a class manually created which look like that :

TestContext.cs

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<TestRq> TestRq { get; set; }
}
```

TestRq.cs

```
[Table("TestRq",Schema = "Test")]
public class TestRq
{
    [Key]
    public decimal RQ {get; set;}
    public string RQ_VALUE {get; set;}
    public decimal RT {get; set;}
    public string RT_SHORT_DESC {get; set;}
}
```

then in my program.cs

I'm just doing this

```
using var testContext = new TestContext("Test");
var testRqFind = testContext.TestRq.Find(3);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
testRqFind = testContext.TestRq.Find(3);
```

from a connection string point of view, as I'm not using any "real" Code-First/Database-First approach, I have a "basic" sqlClient connection string :

`<add name="Test" connectionString="Data source=MySqlServer\SQL22;Database=TestRqDB;User=myUser;Password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

looking at SQL Profiler, we can clearly see that the DbContext execute 2 time the same query.

[image: screenshot of the queries in SQL Profiler]

I did some debugging and the ObjectStateManager does contain the entity in his memory between the 2 find execution. so I have no clue what am I doing wrong here.

any hint on why the find does not take the in-memory entity the second time ?

Comment: [Other docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-an-entity-by-primary-key) show an example almost identical to OP's and claim the DB should only be hit once. Very odd.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yep nice found! this seems very strange, I wanted to post an issue in the GitHub repo of EF6 but they mention in the readme that I'll have more chance getting an answer here.

Comment: I don't agree with that. What you experience here is not expected and not common. If it's a bug in the combination EF6 /.net6 (which is the only thing I can think of) then it belongs on github.

Comment: Just a guess but you use decimal key while searching with ints, maybe can be something there

Comment: @siggemannen, geez you are right... what the heck... that's definitely something I would have never thought of!

thanks for the hint!!

Comment: Hmm, it may be fixed in newer .Net Core versions if that is the case. I was thinking along the same lines but tried it with EF Core and it does execute with just a single call, however if I try to pass an integer value into the `Find` call I get an exception that the type does not match. Earlier Core versions may be doing a conversion which somehow skips/invalidates the local cache check with the type mismatch on PK. If you cast the test value to decimal, i.e. .'.Find(3m)` that might work as expected.

Comment: if it throws an exception in .NET core this is "inline" with the logic.
I can understand that it will not work in both ways if you give int instead of decimal, but making it 50% working makes it very fishy to find out and to understand how the logic is doing.
If you put the debug, you see that it creates an "EntityKey" object which is then compared again the Dictionary<EntityKey,EntityEntry> in the ObjectStateManager, I compared the generated one with the one in memory and the object were 100% the same (same hashcode too)

Comment: Well spotted @siggemannen! I can reproduce this using EF6, both in .net framework 4 and .net6. Using `Find(3m)` fixes it. Leandro, it's probably a waste of time to post a bug report. Only "[High-impact bugs, typically those impacting a very large number of users, *may* be fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6?tab=readme-ov-file#status-and-support)".